# loop each line into array

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to loop an array like this:

```
$output = @(KPScript -c:GetEntryString $PASSHOME\$PASSFILE -pw:$PASS -Field:csname $SEARCH)
$output[3]
foreach ($line in $output) {
    $CSNAME += $line
    if ($line.StartsWith("OK:")) {
        break
    } else {
        Write-Host "CSNAME=$CSNAME"
    }
}
```

and the output is this:

```
covilha2
CSNAME=covilha1
CSNAME=covilha1fundao
CSNAME=covilha1fundaobelmonte
CSNAME=covilha1fundaobelmontecovilha2
```

I can get the `$output[3]` correctly, but I need `$CSNAME` to be an array also with each individual value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `$CSNAME` as an array first. If not you will only append to the first string over and over.

```
$output = @(KPScript -c:GetEntryString $PASSHOME\$PASSFILE -pw:$PASS -Field:csname $SEARCH)
$output[3]

#Declare $CSNAME as array
$CSNAME = @()

foreach ($line in $output) {
    if ($line.StartsWith("OK:")) {
        break
    } else {
        $CSNAME += $line

        #You might want to use CSNAME=$line here so it doesn't output the whole array each time
        Write-Host "CSNAME=$line"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `CSNAME` to be an array:

```
$CSNAME = @()
```

Now you can add names to the array using `$CSNAME += $line`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like:

```
$CSNAME = @($output | %{ if ($_ -like 'OK:*') { continue }; $_ }
```

(Using shortcut syntax to copy lines from `$output` that do not start with "OK:".)

Using an array constructor `@(…)` means you always get an array even if there are zero or one values.

Comment: Note that `? $_ -ne 'OK:'` implements a different logic than what the OP has shown (filtering out lines that contain just the text "OK:" vs. stopping output at the first line that begins with "OK:"). A pipeline equivalent for the latter would have to look like this: `$CSNAME = @($output | % { if ($_ -like 'OK:*') { continue }; $_ }`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes, (and thanks for the typo fix). But clearer to negate the check and avoid the `continue`. (Updating answer,,,)

Comment: That's not what I meant. Consider input like `'foo', 'OK:bar', 'baz'`. The OP's code will output just `foo` while your code will output `foo` and `baz`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Of course (too used to pipelining for PSH... and currently fighting CSS :-))